# Sometimes the smell can be really quite bitter

Tags: riddle, cipher

One day, my sister Ana, a riddle fanatic, wrote me a letter:

> Almonds, don't you think, are really quite delicious (at least, to some point). Sometimes the smell can be really quite bitter. In any case, solve my gram after the code. A hint was already given, so don't ask for any. This is the code;

> $$13.9.21.20.1.16.15.19.19...14.25.3.1.9.4.5.$$

> I just made this one after eating, and it's too late for the hospital. So don't try taking me there, sorry.

She died. How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer:

> POTASSIUM CYANIDE

If you take the numbers to correspond to letters of the alphabet, the code becomes

> MIUTAPOSS... NYCAIDE

Which is an anagram of the answer

The clue is that

> Cyanide is said to smell slightly of almonds

Answer (score 8):

She died from:

> Potassium cyanide

Beacuse:

> Using standard substitution (A=1, B=2) on the numbers, you get **miutaposs** **nycaide**

and that's an anagram of:

> **Potassium cyanide** (poison)

And the clue is because:

> Cyanide has an almond-y smell

Comment: Who said anything about killing? :p

Comment: @manshu Fair enough!  Edited.

Comment: @manshu: If she died by ingesting Potassium Cyanide, the Potassium Cyanide indeed killed her.